# Cancel all threads if one user cancels their thread

Tags: c#

Hey i wanted to ask if there is a way to make a cancellation token unique to each thread .
My code example :

```
public static CancellationTokenSource MyToken{ get; set; }

public static System.Threading.Thread PostThread { get; set; }
       
public static async Task Main()
{
      //somecode and then i call token.Cancel 
      MyToken.Cancel();
}
public static void StartPosting(string sendwhere, int time, Message message)
{
        PostThread = new System.Threading.Thread(async () =>
        {
              var canceltoken =  MyToken.Token;
              while (true)
              {
                  //somecode
                  if (token.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                  {
                        token.Dispose();
                        return;
                  }
                  await Task.Delay((time*60000), canceltoken);
              }
        });
}
```

When two or more users enter their own thread ,
the first user that call the cancellation token cancel all threads .
If someone have also other solution for that i will be glad !
I just need for evey user to be able to stop his own thread when needed.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to better reflect what I believe your actual question is.  Feel free to revert if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Just create a new instance of the cancellation token for each thread, that should suffice. Is there a reason to make your methods  all static?

Comment: @Bruno actually i changed it from static to regular there was no reason , can you give me an example of your solution ? 
because when i create a new canceltoken like you see in my code there is no option to do canceltoken.Dispose(); .. it give the option only for MyToken.Dispose();

Comment: 1) it's incorrect to view the operations as "threads". The thread is an implementation detail; you will have more success if you don't conflate an operation with the thread that handles the operation. 2) if you want each individual operation to be cancelable separately from each other, then each operation needs its own cancel token. See marked duplicates for some examples of how you might go about this.